# get different duration result of a method?

Tags: java

I have simple program to measure the process times of a method. But, I get the different result for each run.
Even I just print out the "Hello" string, I get different result. I thought that I will get the same result. Could you provide some explanation?

```
public static void run() throws Exception {
    double start = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Hello");
    // other operation
    double end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end - start);
}
```

First Result  : 112573.0
Second Result : 122195.0
Third Result  : 293140.0

Comment: The time you are seeing is not constant always because of the system resources and the time of allocation of it.. The output function always takes the same time but depending upon the system resources allocated at that time, the runtime differs.

Comment: @ADi Please provide you explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
From the Java Documentation:

public static long nanoTime()
```

Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer, in nanoseconds.

This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change. Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (263 nanoseconds) will not accurately compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow.

So the `nanoTime` can results different time.

Comment: what about System.currentTimeMillis()??

Comment: @ADi It returns the current time in milliseconds.This method returns the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC(coordinated universal time).

Comment: I know that, Does it have the same error as nanotime??

Answer (score 0):

The time difference you are experiencing because of the system resources and the time of allocation of them. 
The `System.out.println("")` always takes the same time but depending upon the system resources allocated at that time, the run-time differs.

Comment: I think, it is already allocated `max, min memory` for JVM. Even other resource allocated, JVM have specific allocation.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But the its not about memory, its about the availability of resources, and sometimes, it comes to processor resources as well.